# Login to Sharepoint 2013 programatically

Tags: 2013, authentication, sharepoint-server

My business scenario is user have logged in .Net application where I'm redirecting user to SharePoint, here I should avoid another login prompt like FBA or windows authentication, so when i redirect the user to SharePoint, they should be logged in automatically. I can pass user credentials, if needed, but should be via secure channel. I came across Fed Auth and still checking on the same, your expertise can fasten my progress. Please help!

Basically i want to login into SharePoint 2013 without any login prompt. I am the admin and can write SSOM/CSOM via anonymous application page or do any any setup to achieve the same, would appreciate suggestions!

Comment: I guess Single-Sign On isn't an option for you?

Comment: Right, I'm aware of it but want an alternate...

Comment: any suggestions pls?

Comment: surprised to see no answers, any suggestion to get attention would be appreciated :)